# Aligning multiple exposures

Tags: 35mm, minolta, multiple-exposure

I'm mostly using a **Minolta X300** for multi-exposures work.

**My process is as follows:**

1. I make sure the camera's crank is winded;
2. I insert the film into the cylinder making sure the cylinder doesn't move, and make a pen marking of how deep into the cylinder
   the film is pushed;
3. I feel with my thumb where camera's gate is and push to make a marking on each side with my nail or a marker;
4. At the end of the first pass and exposing all the photos, I rewind almost completely and repeat through step one.

This process has brought 90% chance of success, but sometimes for a reason I don't understand, there are 3-4 millimeters of the photos that do not perfectly overlap.

What can I do to better align the exposures of each pass?

Comment: Honestly I'm amazed that you achieved a 90% success rate within a couple millimeters. Normally multiple exposures are done per frame by not advancing or moving the film at all and then taking the second or subsequent shot.

Comment: @user10216038 Yes my process works fairly well. I also use an Olympus om-1n which has a built in multiple exposure system but the results are never as precise, and the following pictures are messed up.